# Best way to extract params from string

Tags: php, string, text-parsing

I have a `name="value"` type string that looks like...

```
{user type="active" name="james green" id="45" group="active users"}
```

I need a generic function that will parse this type of string extracting all of the name/value pairs as an array from this format (always within double quotes and each param sepertated by a space, enclosed in `{}`) as well as the initial opening word (`user` in this case).

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem writing one by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I think you should roll out your own parser. It's an easy syntax, should not take more than a couple of states.

Comment: Simple enough to do with a regex. You can also find a dozen examples for this exact format on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically

```
 preg_match_all('~(\w+)="(.+?)"~', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
 foreach($matches as $m)
     $array[$m[1]] = $m[2]
```

Comment: When you know regexp you're a God :P

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '{user type="active" name="james green" id="45" group="active users"}';
$user = simplexml_load_string('<' . substr($string, 1, -1) .'/>');
print_r(current($user));
```

will give

```
Array
(
    [type] => active
    [name] => james green
    [id] => 45
    [group] => active users
)
```

But that should be easy and more appropriate to solve with a Regex.

Comment: Interesting approach, +1 but I'm gonna stick with regex I think.

Comment: @fire yeah, no problem. Actually I think a Regex is the better choice, too. Using an XML parser demands the string to follow XML syntax rules, which might not apply to your scenario. Regex doesnt have any such constraints, so its likely the better fit here. It was more like lateral thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '{user type="active" name="james green" id="45" group="active users"}';
$string = str_replace('{', '', $string); // delete brackets
$array = explode(' ', $string);

$var = array_shift($array); // <-- here is 'user'

foreach($array as $pair)
{
$arr = explode('=', $pair);
$arr[0]; // <-- here is the key
$arr[1]; // <-- here is the value
}
```

Not tested!

Comment: You can NOT do this with explode. What about Quotes? What if there's space in value? [Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/h6b4Vx)

Comment: I changed `array_pop()` to `array_shift()` pop removes from the end, shift removes from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

name "james green" can be extracted like this

```
<?php
    $point=strpos( $string, 'name="' ) + strlen('name="');
    $string = substr($string,$point);

    $point=strpos( $string, '"' );
    $string = substr($string,$point);

    echo $string; // james green
?>
```